# SQL: Group By specific values and add up their count column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to group a chunk of values into it's own, and get a total count for each group.

```
name|count
alex 3
amy 6

james 3
john 33
joe 12

zane 1
pane 5
```

I have a sql query like this but I think it is incorrect. basically I need to add the total count for each group, and right now it just counts the number of rows.

```
select Name, 
    count(case when Text like 'alex' or Text like 'amy' then 1 end) as group1, 
    count(case when Text like 'j%' then 1 end) as group2,
    count(case when Text like 'zane' or Text like 'pane' then 1 end) as group3,
from MyTable
group by Name
```

The important criteria is that I need to group people by their names, this grouping is not trivial and needs to be done specifically by individual values.

Comment: Replace `COUNT()` with `SUM()` and replace `THEN 1` with `THEN \`count\``.

Comment: doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oh, and drop the `GROUP BY`.